# Java: Searching through unsorted integer array and returning how many numbers are greater

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, java.util.scanner

I've been trying to create a method to search an unsorted integer array but I have come across some issues I just can't get by. I want to allow the user of the program to enter an integer value and have the program return the amount of numbers there are greater than the searched integer value. The problems I seem to be having is with dealing with the variables inside the main method, using scanner for search, and exactly how to go about fixing my loop for this run through.

I'd really appreciate the help!

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog9ArrayMethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Daily high temperatures for Portland Maine Jan 1 - Dec 31 2015
        int[] tmax = {32, 38, 34, 35, 41, 17, 25, 17, 29, 24, 26, 33, 31, 24, 
                      29, 38, 20, 49, 49, 36, 31, 38, 35, 32, 37, 20, 17, 26, 
                      30, 32, 22, 26, 12, 20, 35, 34, 19, 28, 22, 15, 30, 23, 
                      20, 17, 16, 19, 21, 21, 32, 33, 19, 34, 35, 31, 19, 34, 
                      21, 27, 27, 30, 36, 32, 46, 39, 23, 38, 40, 44, 47, 56, 
                      41, 39, 38, 36, 45, 44, 28, 32, 34, 36, 35, 34, 39, 42, 
                      49, 49, 41, 41, 40, 48, 45, 46, 66, 49, 48, 41, 47, 42, 
                      35, 43, 54, 68, 66, 70, 65, 55, 67, 55, 57, 48, 63, 60, 
                      53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 63, 57, 60, 55, 54, 62, 76, 75, 72, 
                      84, 58, 59, 83, 68, 82, 64, 68, 70, 63, 74, 61, 65, 67, 
                      69, 67, 65, 83, 84, 91, 79, 80, 77, 84, 73, 51, 50, 61, 
                      60, 58, 73, 67, 65, 68, 81, 86, 80, 85, 78, 61, 61, 75, 
                      72, 80, 69, 72, 72, 67, 82, 78, 67, 70, 59, 69, 75, 68, 
                      78, 80, 71, 82, 82, 76, 84, 72, 84, 87, 90, 78, 76, 82, 
                      76, 74, 70, 81, 84, 70, 82, 78, 76, 67, 67, 77, 83, 88, 
                      86, 86, 86, 81, 81, 80, 82, 80, 76, 80, 77, 77, 67, 80, 
                      77, 80, 85, 85, 89, 86, 83, 75, 73, 78, 70, 79, 75, 80, 
                      79, 77, 75, 81, 86, 80, 84, 86, 72, 78, 82, 92, 89, 86, 
                      78, 73, 74, 62, 73, 83, 85, 82, 83, 75, 72, 69, 65, 74, 
                      74, 63, 63, 67, 74, 75, 69, 62, 55, 58, 58, 61, 69, 67, 
                      63, 59, 56, 68, 70, 62, 68, 57, 61, 57, 46, 48, 66, 58, 
                      65, 54, 47, 62, 54, 52, 59, 73, 58, 51, 58, 64, 64, 64, 
                      68, 69, 65, 53, 58, 53, 47, 53, 60, 46, 53, 54, 47, 47, 
                      53, 59, 46, 42, 42, 42, 41, 51, 61, 57, 41, 32, 38, 44, 
                      45, 47, 51, 51, 57, 39, 45, 53, 48, 57, 47, 48, 56, 42, 
                      50, 46, 40, 38, 47, 49, 47, 51, 62, 51, 43, 34, 23, 28, 
                      44};

        int max = arrayMax(tmax);
        int min = arrayMin(tmax);
        double average = arrayAverage(tmax);
        int search = arrayIndex(search, tmax); // Not exactly sure how to fix this
        System.out.println("Maximum value is: " + max);
        System.out.println("Minimum value is: " + min);
        System.out.println("Average value is: " + average);
        System.out.println("The number of values above the specified value is: " + search);
    }

    // Returns the maximum value in the array
    public static int arrayMax(int[] a) {
        int max = a[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] > max)
                max = a[i];

        return max; 
    }
    // Returns the minimum value in the array
    public static int arrayMin (int[] a) {
        int min = a[0];    

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                if (a[i] < min)
                    min = a[i];
            return min;
    }
    public static double arrayAverage(int[] a) {  
        int sum = 0; // Why does it double the decimal value with "int sum = a[0]"?
        double average;

            for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
                sum = sum + a[i];
            }
            average = (double)sum/a.length;
            return average;
    }
    public static int arrayIndex(int userSearch, int[] a) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Enter a value to search: ");
        userSearch = user_input.next(); // What else could I use?

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i] > userSearch) {
                return a[i]; // Return a value that represents how many numbers are above the search varaible
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have to rewrite your arrayIndex method. Take the input from the user inside that method or you can pass the input to the arrayIndex method.

Just count the number greater than input and then return the result.

```
public static int arrayIndex(int[] a) {

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println("Enter a value to search: ");
    int userSearch = user_input.nextInt(); 

    int numberOfCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] > userSearch) {
            ++numberOfCount;
        }
    }
    return numberOfCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty easy. I'll explain it.

```
public static int arrayIndex(int userSearch, int[] a) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int count = 0;//this will track your data
        System.out.println("Enter a value to search: ");
        userSearch = user_input.nextInt(); // Use nextInt()

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i] > userSearch) {
                 count++;//increments when the if statement is true
            }
        }
        return count;//returns your desired data
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the call to arrayIndex:

```
 int search = arrayIndex( tmax); // no need to pass userSearch:
```

Here is how you read an integer using scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int userSearch = scanner.nextInt();
```

But wait: There is more. If you use java 8 streams your code can be cleaned up quite a bit:

```
// Returns the maximum value in the array
public static int arrayMax(int[] a) {
    return Arrays.stream(a).max().getAsInt();
}
// Returns the minimum value in the array
public static int arrayMin (int[] a) {
    return Arrays.stream(a).min().getAsInt();
}
public static double arrayAverage(int[] a) {
    return Arrays.stream(a).average().getAsDouble();
}

public static long arrayIndex( int[] a) {

    System.out.println("Enter a value to search: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userSearch = scanner.nextInt();

    return Arrays.stream(a).filter(n -> n > userSearch).count();
}
```

Have a look and enjoy!